# Скорость обработки запросов ботом

Tags: vkontakte-api, api, бот

вопрос к людям разбирающимся в ботах. Написал бота для группы VK на python, бот работает через лонгпул, а сообщения обрабатывает в отдельных потоках, скорость обработки и ответа на первое сообщение в среднем 0.22 секунды, вопрос, насколько это плохо/хорошо/нормально для бота и к какой скорости обработки нужно стремиться?

Comment: А какая у Вас задача? Фактическую скорость ответа можно улучшить, используя `Callback API`. Также можно вынести часть логики в [`execute`](https://vk.com/dev.php?method=execute). Но так ли это нужно на самом деле?

Comment: Задача - обработка соотвествующих комманд, работа с БД sqlite почти при каждой комманде, но как я понял по вашему ответу, я пока в этом не нуждаюсь

Comment: Хорошо или плохо всегда зависит от требований. Какая пиковая нагрузка у вас планируется? Что будет при обработке не одного, а сразу 100 сообщений в минуту? Не провиснет ли база/сервер? Можно ли будет развернуть 2й сервер? Время нужно считать не по первому сообщению, а усредненное, минут за 10 например, с разной нагрузкой.

Answer (score 0):

Чтобы сильно не нагружать бота, ставьте time.sleep на 1.5 сек . Это время чаще всего встречается у ботов